# Redirecting in a PHP page to another PHP page

Tags: php

I have a register.php, login.php, and main.php. How do i redirect user after after registration submit to login page and then login page submit to main page.

Answer (score 7):

```
header("Location: /login.php");
exit;
```

See the `exit`. Don't *ever* forget to do this. If you have sensitive data after this, it will be visible to anyone that doesn't follow location headers ([such as some bots](http://ww.thedailywtf.com/Articles/WellIntentioned-Destruction.aspx)).

To stop you from forgetting, you could build a wrapper type function

```
function redirect($url) {
    header('Location: ' . $url);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that Google wouldn't follow that, but I may be wrong. They follow 301's and 302's just fine... what's the default Status Code sent along with PHP via Location?

Comment: @anonymous coward I read a 'Daily WTF' recently where they had pages deleted from a custom CMS because the Internet Archive bot didn't follow the `Location` headers. I mixed up Google bot with them.

Comment: Wait, why are you outputting sensitive data in the first place?

Comment: Well someone might have something like `if ( ! $loggedIn) { header('Location: login.php'); echo 'you must be logged in' }`. Not saying that is best practice but I'm sure some people may do it.

Answer (score 3):

```
header("Location: /login.php");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: I generally add `die("Redirecting...");` after the header, just to make sure nothing else is outputted.

Comment: @webdestroya - Isn't that a bit misleading, on account of if the user can see that, the redirect has failed?

Comment: The user rarely sees it, and if they do it just means their browser is slow, not that the redirect has failed.

Comment: @webdestroya I don't think it means their browser is slow? More like it is refusing to follow `Location` headers. Perhaps I'm wrong though.

Comment: Maybe, but the probability that a browser will not respect the Location header is incredibly low.

Comment: use `ob_start()` at the top and `ob_end_flush()` at the bottom of each php page where u use `header()` in between of page i.e if `header()` is called after any actual output is sent

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

**func.php**

```
<?php
function EmptyStr($value){
   $str = strval($value);
   $str = str_replace("&nbsp;", "", $str);
   return (trim($str) == "");
}

function redirect($url) {
header('Location: ' . $url);
exit;
}
?>
```

**register.php**

```
<?php
include("func.php");
$username = $_POST["username];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
if(!EmptyStr($username) && !EmptyStr($password) && !EmptyStr($email)){
   sql = WRITE YOUR SQL SYNTAX HERE TO INSERT THE INPUT TO DB
   redirect("/login.php");
}else{
   $_SESSION["ErrMsg"] = "Error! All fields are required.";
}

echo $_SESSION["ErrMsg"];
$_SESSION["ErrMsg"] = "";
?>
Put your html regsitration form here
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
include("func.php");
$username = $_POST["username];
$password = $_POST["password"];

if(!EmptyStr($username) && !EmptyStr($password)){
   sql = WRITE YOUR SQL SYNTAX HERE TO QUERY THE USERNAME AND PASSWORD TO DB
   if ($rs && !$rs->EOF) {  //user found and pass match
      $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
      redirect("/main.php");
   }else{
      $_SESSION["ErrMsg"] = "Invalid username or passsword!";
   }
}else{
   $_SESSION["ErrMsg"] = "Error! All fields are required.";
}

echo $_SESSION["ErrMsg"];
$_SESSION["ErrMsg"] = "";
?>

Put your html login form here
```

**main.php**

```
<?php
include("func.php");
if(EmptyStr($_SESSION["username"])){ //check if user has session (logged in)
   $_SESSION["ErrMsg"] = "You need to logged in first to view this page!";
   redirect("/login.php");
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
`Header("Location:login.php");`
```

or:
`echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content='0; url=login.php'>";`

or:

```
echo "<script language='javascript'>";
echo "location='login.php';";
echo "</script>";
```

Comment: Never count on Javascript to perform a mission critical redirect.